# how to set JFrame form as main class in netbeans (linux)

Tags: linux, swing, netbeans, jframe

in netbeans (windows edition) we can make a new independent JFrame form that is run as main class .
but in netbeans (linux edition) i made a new project and delete main class file and then create an empty  JFrame form (and it has public static void main(String args[]) )
but when i press the run button in netbeans i get this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

but when i right-click on the JFrame form file(the name is MyApp.java)
and click run ... the form shows corectly!
how can i fix this problem?
(my IDE is netbeans 11.3 and my OS is debian 10.3)

Answer (score 0):

i changed file name from "MyApp.java" to "Main.java" and problem solved !